# Algorithm to select elements from a ranked list of lists

Tags: algorithms

I have a list of lists of objects. Each of the lists of objects is ranked according to a numeric field of the object. The big list is ranked according to the highest numeric value of the field of all the objects in a list of objects.

I want to select elements from each of the lists of objects, but obviously want to weight elements which are ranked higher more heavily. I also want diversity in my selection, i.e., I want some objects from every list, and for objects from any one single list to be spread out.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm? Or perhaps are there any academic papers you can refer me to, or a general topic/famous problem that this problem is related to? Thanks.

Comment: `[I] want to weight elements which are ranked higher more heavily` without an explanation what this means, consider "random" selection and try to pin down how to tell bad from acceptable from good. Have a look at "randomness tests" and [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence).